# How to center text with logo in the middle of it in navbar bulma

Tags: html, css, bulma

I'm trying to center text inside navbar with the logo being in between navbar items, however, I was only able to center logo as brand image.
[image]

Here's my code:

```
<a role="button" class="navbar-burger" aria-label="menu" data-target="navMenu" aria-expanded="false">
<span aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true"></span>
  </a>
<nav class="navbar is-white">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
      <a class="navbar-item" href="/">
        <img src='img/logo.png' style="width: 100px;">
      </a>
  <div class="navbar-menu" id="navMenu">
        <div class="navbar-start">
        <a href="#" class="navbar-item nav-text">Paslaugos</a>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-item nav-text">Kainos</a>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-item nav-text">DUK</a>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-item nav-text">Apie Mus</a>
      </div>

  </div>

</nav>
```

css

```
.navbar .navbar-brand {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar .navbar-brand > .navbar-item,
.navbar .navbar-brand .navbar-link {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated I have already spent way too much time on this.

Comment: Why not put the img in between the `<a>` ?

Comment: yeah it works but I have no idea hot to center it andbe responsive on mobile as well

Comment: make the wrapper that wraps the links `inline-block `then have `text-align:center;` on the parent of that wrapper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Considerations

Divide the container inside the navbar into three columns.

```
<div id="my-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Items left -->
    <div></div>
    <!-- Logo in the center -->
    <div></div>
    <!-- Items right -->
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Set `flex: 1` to make each column in `.container` the same width.

**Note**

Of course, if there are more items, e.g. on the left side than on the right side, the items are **smaller**.

#### Example

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#my-navbar img {
  display: block;
}

#my-navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#my-navbar {
  background: #151515;
  padding: 10px;
}

#my-navbar .container,
#my-navbar .container>div {
  display: flex;
}

#my-navbar .container {
  /* Set a max width to squeeze the navbar */
  max-width: 600px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#my-navbar .container>div {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  #my-navbar .container {
    margin: 0;
  }
  #my-navbar .container,
  #my-navbar .container>div {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  #my-navbar .item {
    margin: 5px;
  }
  #my-navbar .container>div:nth-child(1) {
    order: 2;
  }
  #my-navbar .container>div:nth-child(2) {
    order: 1;
  }
  #my-navbar .container>div:nth-child(3) {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="my-navbar">
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <div class="item"><a href="">Link</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><a href="">Link</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><a href="">Link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x50" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div class="item"><a href="">Link</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><a href="">Link</a>
      </div>
      <div class="item"><a href="">Link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

### Complete Bulma solution

Don't forget to set a media query so that it **doesn't affect** mobile screens.

```
@media screen and (...) {}
```

In this case, Bulma uses `min-width: 1088px`.

**Hint**

The `.navbar-burger` is **inside** the `.navbar-brand`:
[Bulma navbar](https://bulma.io/documentation/components/navbar/)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  // Get all "navbar-burger" elements
  var $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.navbar-burger'), 0);

  // Check if there are any navbar burgers
  if ($navbarBurgers.length > 0) {

    // Add a click event on each of them
    $navbarBurgers.forEach(function($el) {
      $el.addEventListener('click', function() {

        // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
        var target = $el.dataset.target;
        var $target = document.getElementById(target);

        // Toggle the class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
        $el.classList.toggle('is-active');
        $target.classList.toggle('is-active');

      });
    });
  }

});
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1088px) {
  #my-navbar-menu>div {
    flex: 1;
  }
  #my-navbar-menu>div>div {
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <div class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="my-navbar-menu">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="my-navbar-menu" class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Site</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Site</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Site</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-navbar-center">
      <div class="navbar-item"><img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" alt="Bulma: a modern CSS framework based on Flexbox" width="112" height="28">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-end">
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Site</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Site</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

#### Squeeze the navbar

To **keep** the **flex behavior** for the **items** in the navbar menu, the easiest way would be to set `display: block` for the navbar and a **width** for the navbar menu and center it with `margin: 0 auto`.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 1088px) {
  .my-navbar {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .my-navbar .navbar-brand {
    display: none;
  }
  #my-navbar-menu {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  #my-navbar-menu>div {
    flex: 1;
  }
  #my-navbar-menu>div>div {
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar my-navbar">
  <div class="navbar-brand">
    <div class="navbar-burger burger" data-target="my-navbar-menu">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="my-navbar-menu" class="navbar-menu">
    <div class="navbar-start">
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Site</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Site</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Site</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="my-navbar-center">
      <div class="navbar-item"><img src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png" alt="Bulma: a modern CSS framework based on Flexbox" width="112" height="28">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-end">
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Site</a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-item"><a href="#">Site</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want the simplicity of a pure CSS implementation then check [Bulma layout > level](https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/level/#centered-level) out:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try using the flex property. To the container div you can give

```
<div class="flexcontainer">


<ul>
  <li>home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li><img src="http://www.monodies.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/facebook-Icon-290x290.png"></li>
  <li>link</li>
  <li>link</li>
</ul>
</div>

.flexcontainer{
  display:flex;
}
.flexcontainer ul{
  display:flex;
  list-style:none;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;

}
```

check this https://jsfiddle.net/karantewari/bqh9byj3/ , hope it helps :)