# How could I do a navigation bar that fill the screen?

Tags: html, css

[image]
I am beginner.
I want to make a similar bar to this, but I do not succeed to make the bar fill all the screen and I have no idea how I could make the text to be aligned as in the picture.

To put that logo in the middle of the div I used this id.

```
#clogo {
    height: 50px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;            
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50300283/3589620

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use`display: flex` to center items and `width: 100%` to make the navbar full width like so:

HTML:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>link1</li>
    <li>link2</li>
    <li>link3</li>
    <li>link4</li>
    <li>link5</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 50px;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```