# How can I center the logo and navigation horizontally on the same line?

Tags: html, css

New to HTML/CSS and my biggest struggle currently is creating navigation bars with logos. I am setting up a horizontal navigation bar with the logo image to the left of the nav. I want both the nav and image in the center of the site. My nav is not perfectly centered and my logo is off to the right and not lined up with the nav links.

I have tried `flex`, `float`, and `margin`, but have not had any luck.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}

header {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 25px 0 25px 0;
}


/* Navigation */

.main-logo {}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav a {
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Links */

a:hover {
  color: #a8a8a8;
}

body a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

.intro-content {
  padding-top: 170px;
  height: 850px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, transparent 90%), linear-gradient(0deg, #000, transparent), #ffa949 url('img/header-bg.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.intro-content h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3.25rem;
  /* 26px/16px */
  letter-spacing: .065em;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 75px 0 5px 0;
}

.main-content,
.intro-content,
.main-footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-content {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 95px;
}

.secondary-content {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dfe2e6;
}

.socialmedia {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0 20px 0;
}

.socialmedia a {
  margin: 0 25px 0 25px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.main-footer {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.t-border {
  border-top: 2px solid #dfe2e6;
}


/* Layout */

.main-content,
.secondary-content {
  width: 75%;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}


/* Floats */

.article1,
.article2 {
  width: 40%;
}

.article2 {
  float: left;
}

.article1 {
  float: right;
}


/* Float Clearfix */

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
  <html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta charset="UTF-utf-8">
    <title>100 Thieves | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ab11039b93.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="main-logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="Img/100Thieves.png" alt="100 Thieves Logo"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="main-nav">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="intro-content">
      <h1>Take What's Not Given</h1>
      <p>The words of Matt "Nadeshot" Haag and the official 100 Thieves motto</p>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content">

      <div class="about">
        <h2>About 100 Thieves</h2>
        <p>100 Thieves is a new gaming lifestyle company and eSports organization built at the intersection of competitive gaming, entertainment, and apparel. 100 Thieves was founded in 2017 by Matt "Nadeshot" Haag, the former Optic Gaming Call of Duty captain,
          X Games gold medalist, and 2014 eSports athlete of the year. After retiring from competitive play, Matt went on to build some of the most popular gaming channels on twitch and youtube, and then founded 100 Thieves as a creative outlet for his
          passions in competitive gaming, storytelling, and streetwear. The company currently competes in professional League of Legends, Call of Duty, Fortnite and Apex Legends.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="cashapp">
        <h2>About Cash App</h2>
        <p>Cash App is the money app. It's the easiest way to pay people back—friends, family, coworkers—anyone, really. Sending and receiving money is totally free and fast, and most payments can be deposited directly to your bank account in just a few
          seconds. With cash app, you can also buy and sell bitcoin instantly, get a paycheck deposited right to the app, or create a unique $cashtag that you can share with anyone to get paid fast. You can even use the free cash card to spend the money
          you keep in the app anywhere you like. Customize your card with a laser-etching and add a boost from the app to instantly save at some of your favorite places whenever you swipe.
          <a href="http://www.cash.app/download">Download</a> cash app for free.
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="secondary-content t-border group">

      <div class="article1">
        <img src="Img/win.png" alt="100 Thieves wins at CWL London">
        <h2>Big Win at CWL London</h2>
        <p>100 Thieves won their first ever Call of Duty eSports title on May 5, 2019. After knocking out top teams like Envy, Team Heretics, and Team Reciprocity, and sweeping OpTic Gaming aside with ease, 100 Thieves was matched against eUnited. It was
          a close fought affair all through the match, and with both teams mere seconds away from claiming victory, 100 Thieves managed to hold on to the point and won the final map 250-238.
          <p><a href="https://www.gamesradar.com/cwl-london-2019-recap-winner/">Read more...</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="article2">
        <img src="Img/franchise.png" alt="100 Thieves gunning for the Los Angeles franchise">
        <h2>Gunning the Los Angeles Franchise</h2>
        <p>One of the most sought after spots in the competition is the Los Angeles franchise, and according to reports 100 Thieves are hoping to raise more money in the hopes of locking down the California position. If successful, it’s believed that 100
          Thieves would be the sole team based in Los Angeles in the Call of Duty franchise league, an ideal situation as the team’s headquarters and LCS teams are both based in the city.</p>
        <p><a href="https://www.dexerto.com/call-of-duty/100-thieves-reportedly-raising-25-million-for-call-of-duty-franchise-spot-675708">Read more...</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="socialmedia">
      <h3>Follow 100 Thieves</h3>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/100Thieves"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="http://instagram.com/100thieves"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/100thieves"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/team/100thieves"><i class="fab fa-twitch"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="main-footer">
      <footer>
        &copy; 100 Thieves, LLC 2019
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: can you give us logo image URL ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center text with logo in the middle of it in navbar bulma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50298828/how-to-center-text-with-logo-in-the-middle-of-it-in-navbar-bulma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `display: flex` CSS property in your header tag to inline both your navigation and logo, after I added `margin-left: auto` property to align your navigation to right and remove `margin-top` property from `li`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}

header {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 25px 0 25px 0;
  display: flex;
}

/* Navigation */

.main-logo {

}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav a {
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-nav li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Links */

a:hover {
  color: #a8a8a8;
}

body a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

.intro-content {
  padding-top: 170px;
  height: 850px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, transparent 90%),
              linear-gradient(0deg, #000, transparent),
              #ffa949 url('img/header-bg.jpg') no-repeat center;

  background-size: cover;
}

.intro-content h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3.25rem; /* 26px/16px */
  letter-spacing: .065em;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 75px 0 5px 0;
}

.main-content,
.intro-content,
.main-footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-content {
    padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 95px;
}

.secondary-content {
  text-align: center;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dfe2e6;
}

.socialmedia {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0 20px 0;
}

.socialmedia a {
  margin: 0 25px 0 25px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.main-footer {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.t-border {
  border-top: 2px solid #dfe2e6;
}

/* Layout */

.main-content,
.secondary-content {
  width: 75%;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}

/* Floats */

.article1,
.article2 {
  width: 40%;
}

.article2 {
  float: left;
}

.article1 {
  float: right;
}

/* Float Clearfix */

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <meta charset="UTF-utf-8">
        <title>100 Thieves | Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ab11039b93.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <div class="main-logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="Img/100Thieves.png" alt="100 Thieves Logo"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="main-nav">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>

        <div class="intro-content">
            <h1>Take What's Not Given</h1>
            <p>The words of Matt "Nadeshot" Haag and the official 100 Thieves motto</p>
        </div>

        <div class="main-content">

          <div class="about">
            <h2>About 100 Thieves</h2>
            <p>100 Thieves is a new gaming lifestyle company and eSports organization built at the intersection of competitive gaming, entertainment, and apparel. 100 Thieves was founded in 2017 by Matt "Nadeshot" Haag, the former Optic Gaming Call of Duty captain, X Games gold medalist, and 2014 eSports athlete of the year.
            After retiring from competitive play, Matt went on to build some of the most popular gaming channels on twitch and youtube, and then founded 100 Thieves as a creative outlet for his passions in competitive gaming, storytelling, and streetwear. The company currently competes in professional League of Legends, Call of Duty, Fortnite and Apex Legends.
            </p>
          </div>

          <div class="cashapp">
            <h2>About Cash App</h2>
            <p>Cash App is the money app. It's the easiest way to pay people back—friends, family, coworkers—anyone, really. Sending and receiving money is totally free and fast, and most payments can be deposited directly to your bank account in just a few seconds. With cash app, you can also buy and sell bitcoin instantly, get a paycheck deposited right to the app, or create a unique $cashtag that you can share with anyone to get paid fast. You can even use the free cash card to spend the money you keep in the app anywhere you like. Customize your card with a laser-etching and add a boost from the app to instantly save at some of your favorite places whenever you swipe.
            <a href="http://www.cash.app/download">Download</a> cash app for free.
            </p>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="secondary-content t-border group">

          <div class="article1">
            <img src="Img/win.png" alt="100 Thieves wins at CWL London">
            <h2>Big Win at CWL London</h2>
            <p>100 Thieves won their first ever Call of Duty eSports title on May 5, 2019. After knocking out top teams like Envy, Team Heretics, and Team Reciprocity, and sweeping OpTic Gaming aside with ease, 100 Thieves was matched against eUnited. It was a close fought affair all through the match, and with both teams mere seconds away from claiming victory, 100 Thieves managed to hold on to the point and won the final map 250-238.
            <p><a href="https://www.gamesradar.com/cwl-london-2019-recap-winner/">Read more...</a></p>
          </div>

          <div class="article2">
            <img src="Img/franchise.png" alt="100 Thieves gunning for the Los Angeles franchise">
            <h2>Gunning the Los Angeles Franchise</h2>
            <p>One of the most sought after spots in the competition is the Los Angeles franchise, and according to reports 100 Thieves are hoping to raise more money in the hopes of locking down the California position. If successful, it’s believed that 100 Thieves would be the sole team based in Los Angeles in the Call of Duty franchise league, an ideal situation as the team’s headquarters and LCS teams are both based in the city.</p>
            <p><a href="https://www.dexerto.com/call-of-duty/100-thieves-reportedly-raising-25-million-for-call-of-duty-franchise-spot-675708">Read more...</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="socialmedia">
          <h3>Follow 100 Thieves</h3>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/100Thieves"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="http://instagram.com/100thieves"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.youtube.com/100thieves"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
          <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/team/100thieves"><i class="fab fa-twitch"></i></a>
        </div>

      <div class="main-footer">
        <footer>
          &copy; 100 Thieves, LLC 2019
        </footer>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: glad you like my answer :D

Comment: Note that if you run the code snippet in the embedded view, the nav links are directly on top of the logo. [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/xUJmPkI)

Comment: this is about responsive feature, here we only for gave problem's solution, after that you need to solve the pros self

Comment: for that you need to make burger or hamburger menu to collapse your all menus

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the logo you can use `text-align: center;`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}

header {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 25px 0 25px 0;
}


/* Navigation */

.main-logo {
 text-align: center;
}

.main-nav {
   
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 40%;
  list-style: none;
}

.main-nav a {
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-nav li {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Links */

a:hover {
  color: #a8a8a8;
}

body a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

.intro-content {
  padding-top: 170px;
  height: 850px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, transparent 90%), linear-gradient(0deg, #000, transparent), #ffa949 url('img/header-bg.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.intro-content h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3.25rem;
  /* 26px/16px */
  letter-spacing: .065em;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 75px 0 5px 0;
}

.main-content,
.intro-content,
.main-footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-content {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 95px;
}

.secondary-content {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dfe2e6;
}

.socialmedia {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0 20px 0;
}

.socialmedia a {
  margin: 0 25px 0 25px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.main-footer {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.t-border {
  border-top: 2px solid #dfe2e6;
}


/* Layout */

.main-content,
.secondary-content {
  width: 75%;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}


/* Floats */

.article1,
.article2 {
  width: 40%;
}

.article2 {
  float: left;
}

.article1 {
  float: right;
}


/* Float Clearfix */

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="main-logo" >
        <a style=" margin: auto;" href="index.html"><img src="Img/100Thieves.png" alt="100 Thieves Logo"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="main-nav">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="intro-content">
      <h1>Take What's Not Given</h1>
      <p>The words of Matt "Nadeshot" Haag and the official 100 Thieves motto</p>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content">

      <div class="about">
        <h2>About 100 Thieves</h2>
        <p>100 Thieves is a new gaming lifestyle company and eSports organization built at the intersection of competitive gaming, entertainment, and apparel. 100 Thieves was founded in 2017 by Matt "Nadeshot" Haag, the former Optic Gaming Call of Duty captain,
          X Games gold medalist, and 2014 eSports athlete of the year. After retiring from competitive play, Matt went on to build some of the most popular gaming channels on twitch and youtube, and then founded 100 Thieves as a creative outlet for his
          passions in competitive gaming, storytelling, and streetwear. The company currently competes in professional League of Legends, Call of Duty, Fortnite and Apex Legends.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="cashapp">
        <h2>About Cash App</h2>
        <p>Cash App is the money app. It's the easiest way to pay people back—friends, family, coworkers—anyone, really. Sending and receiving money is totally free and fast, and most payments can be deposited directly to your bank account in just a few
          seconds. With cash app, you can also buy and sell bitcoin instantly, get a paycheck deposited right to the app, or create a unique $cashtag that you can share with anyone to get paid fast. You can even use the free cash card to spend the money
          you keep in the app anywhere you like. Customize your card with a laser-etching and add a boost from the app to instantly save at some of your favorite places whenever you swipe.
          <a href="http://www.cash.app/download">Download</a> cash app for free.
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="secondary-content t-border group">

      <div class="article1">
        <img src="Img/win.png" alt="100 Thieves wins at CWL London">
        <h2>Big Win at CWL London</h2>
        <p>100 Thieves won their first ever Call of Duty eSports title on May 5, 2019. After knocking out top teams like Envy, Team Heretics, and Team Reciprocity, and sweeping OpTic Gaming aside with ease, 100 Thieves was matched against eUnited. It was
          a close fought affair all through the match, and with both teams mere seconds away from claiming victory, 100 Thieves managed to hold on to the point and won the final map 250-238.
          <p><a href="https://www.gamesradar.com/cwl-london-2019-recap-winner/">Read more...</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="article2">
        <img src="Img/franchise.png" alt="100 Thieves gunning for the Los Angeles franchise">
        <h2>Gunning the Los Angeles Franchise</h2>
        <p>One of the most sought after spots in the competition is the Los Angeles franchise, and according to reports 100 Thieves are hoping to raise more money in the hopes of locking down the California position. If successful, it’s believed that 100
          Thieves would be the sole team based in Los Angeles in the Call of Duty franchise league, an ideal situation as the team’s headquarters and LCS teams are both based in the city.</p>
        <p><a href="https://www.dexerto.com/call-of-duty/100-thieves-reportedly-raising-25-million-for-call-of-duty-franchise-spot-675708">Read more...</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="socialmedia">
      <h3>Follow 100 Thieves</h3>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/100Thieves"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="http://instagram.com/100thieves"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/100thieves"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/team/100thieves"><i class="fab fa-twitch"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="main-footer">
      <footer>
        &copy; 100 Thieves, LLC 2019
      </footer>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

- Set `display: flex; justify-content: center;` on `header` to get the logo and the nav container side by side and centered.
- Set `display: flex; align-items: center; flex-wrap: wrap;` on `.main-nav ul` to get all `li` to be side by side and vertically centered with the logo. Wrapping lets the elements shift to the next row when they run out of container width.

  - Not quite sure what you're trying to do with the `width: 40%;` on `.main-nav ul`. Left it as is but the links align differently on different width screens obviously. Would `flex: 1;` be a better fit to take up any remaining space on the container?
  - You can see the difference from the `width: 40%;` by running the snippet in embedded mode and when you click "Expand snippet" to view it full screen on a desktop.
- Set `display: flex; align-items: center;` on `.main-logo` to vertically center the logo with the nav links. Also had to set `display: block;` on `.main-logo img` to get the image to respect the vertical align.
- Used a random logo for visualization purposes.
- Removed other positioning related styles between `header` and `.main-nav ul li a`.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
}

header {
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 25px 0 25px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Navigation */

.main-logo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-logo img {
  display: block;
}

.main-nav {}

.main-nav ul {
  width: 40%;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main-nav a {
  color: #fff;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-nav li {
  padding: 0;
}


/* Links */

a:hover {
  color: #a8a8a8;
}

body a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

.intro-content {
  padding-top: 170px;
  height: 850px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, transparent 90%), linear-gradient(0deg, #000, transparent), #ffa949 url('img/header-bg.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.intro-content h1 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 3.25rem;
  /* 26px/16px */
  letter-spacing: .065em;
  font-weight: 200;
  padding: 75px 0 5px 0;
}

.main-content,
.intro-content,
.main-footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-content {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 95px;
}

.secondary-content {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #dfe2e6;
}

.socialmedia {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 50px 0 20px 0;
}

.socialmedia a {
  margin: 0 25px 0 25px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.main-footer {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.t-border {
  border-top: 2px solid #dfe2e6;
}


/* Layout */

.main-content,
.secondary-content {
  width: 75%;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 960px;
}


/* Floats */

.article1,
.article2 {
  width: 40%;
}

.article2 {
  float: left;
}

.article1 {
  float: right;
}


/* Float Clearfix */

.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
  <html lang="en-US" dir="ltr">

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta charset="UTF-utf-8">
    <title>100 Thieves | Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ab11039b93.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="main-logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/50" alt="100 Thieves Logo"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="main-nav">
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="intro-content">
      <h1>Take What's Not Given</h1>
      <p>The words of Matt "Nadeshot" Haag and the official 100 Thieves motto</p>
    </div>

    <div class="main-content">

      <div class="about">
        <h2>About 100 Thieves</h2>
        <p>100 Thieves is a new gaming lifestyle company and eSports organization built at the intersection of competitive gaming, entertainment, and apparel. 100 Thieves was founded in 2017 by Matt "Nadeshot" Haag, the former Optic Gaming Call of Duty captain,
          X Games gold medalist, and 2014 eSports athlete of the year. After retiring from competitive play, Matt went on to build some of the most popular gaming channels on twitch and youtube, and then founded 100 Thieves as a creative outlet for his
          passions in competitive gaming, storytelling, and streetwear. The company currently competes in professional League of Legends, Call of Duty, Fortnite and Apex Legends.
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="cashapp">
        <h2>About Cash App</h2>
        <p>Cash App is the money app. It's the easiest way to pay people back—friends, family, coworkers—anyone, really. Sending and receiving money is totally free and fast, and most payments can be deposited directly to your bank account in just a few
          seconds. With cash app, you can also buy and sell bitcoin instantly, get a paycheck deposited right to the app, or create a unique $cashtag that you can share with anyone to get paid fast. You can even use the free cash card to spend the money
          you keep in the app anywhere you like. Customize your card with a laser-etching and add a boost from the app to instantly save at some of your favorite places whenever you swipe.
          <a href="http://www.cash.app/download">Download</a> cash app for free.
        </p>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="secondary-content t-border group">

      <div class="article1">
        <img src="Img/win.png" alt="100 Thieves wins at CWL London">
        <h2>Big Win at CWL London</h2>
        <p>100 Thieves won their first ever Call of Duty eSports title on May 5, 2019. After knocking out top teams like Envy, Team Heretics, and Team Reciprocity, and sweeping OpTic Gaming aside with ease, 100 Thieves was matched against eUnited. It was
          a close fought affair all through the match, and with both teams mere seconds away from claiming victory, 100 Thieves managed to hold on to the point and won the final map 250-238.
          <p><a href="https://www.gamesradar.com/cwl-london-2019-recap-winner/">Read more...</a></p>
      </div>

      <div class="article2">
        <img src="Img/franchise.png" alt="100 Thieves gunning for the Los Angeles franchise">
        <h2>Gunning the Los Angeles Franchise</h2>
        <p>One of the most sought after spots in the competition is the Los Angeles franchise, and according to reports 100 Thieves are hoping to raise more money in the hopes of locking down the California position. If successful, it’s believed that 100
          Thieves would be the sole team based in Los Angeles in the Call of Duty franchise league, an ideal situation as the team’s headquarters and LCS teams are both based in the city.</p>
        <p><a href="https://www.dexerto.com/call-of-duty/100-thieves-reportedly-raising-25-million-for-call-of-duty-franchise-spot-675708">Read more...</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="socialmedia">
      <h3>Follow 100 Thieves</h3>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/100Thieves"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="http://instagram.com/100thieves"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/100thieves"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
      <a href="https://www.twitch.tv/team/100thieves"><i class="fab fa-twitch"></i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="main-footer">
      <footer>
        &copy; 100 Thieves, LLC 2019
      </footer>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: you don't know question correctly, please watch question first and after answer it

Comment: Ah, ok. I thought "I want both the nav and image in the center of the site" meant he wanted both the nav and image to be in the **center** of the site but he actually wanted the nav **all the way to the right** and image **all the way to the left**, so *not actually center*.